# How to create these 3-D latte art?

Tags: latte-art

My family and I went to a coffee shop in Japan specifically to try their 3-D latte's, my wife ordered one where it featured I think 2 bears or a bear and rabbit as you can see.

How can I recreate these babies at home?

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: This may be helpful: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foam

Comment: They are the newest scoulpture sensation, latte sculptures

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This video here seems to have a good tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTZNs2Mjxos

The steps seem to be as follow:

1. Make your latte as normal, heating/frothing the milk as you normally would - a [microfoam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfoam).
2. Make a *separate* batch of frothed milk, and froth it a lot - you want a really stiff foam - a *macrofoam*.
3. Spoon the stiff foam carefully onto the top of your latte. If you've got it right, the dollops should just sit there and retain their shape. Keep spooning it on to build the shape you want. For your linked images, this is obviously quite a lot of dollops of various sizes.
4. Use a paintbrush to paint the darker areas onto the foam with espresso. It looks like your example has a variety of colours. This is probably done with food dye and/or chocolate.
5. Enjoy destroying your painstakingly produced work of art for the sake of your next caffeine fix!